# How to compare two data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

df1

```
 index           Count
 Duliajan Area      2
 HAPJAN             2
 KATHALGURI         2
```

df2

```
 Location           Category
0        NAGAJAN        0
1        JORAJAN        0
2     KATHALGURI        0
3         HEBEDA        0
4          MAKUM        0
5       BAREKURI        0
6        BAGHJAN        0
7  Duliajan Area        0
8      LANGKASHI        0
9         HAPJAN        0
```

I need this output:

```
0        NAGAJAN        0
1        JORAJAN        0
2     KATHALGURI        2
3         HEBEDA        0
4          MAKUM        0
5       BAREKURI        0
6        BAGHJAN        0
7  Duliajan Area        2
8      LANGKASHI        0
9         HAPJAN        2
```

Comment: @Corralien it was covered in the duplicate, `map` should be used here `df2['Location'].map(df1.set_index('index')['Count']).fillna(df2['Count'])`

Comment: @mozway. OK I closed the question. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `dict` from two columns of `df1` then using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on the `df2`.

```
d = dict(zip(df1['index'], df1['Count']))
df2['Category'] = df2['Location'].map(d).fillna(df2['Category']).astype(int)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
        Location  Category
0        NAGAJAN         0
1        JORAJAN         0
2     KATHALGURI         2
3         HEBEDA         0
4          MAKUM         0
5       BAREKURI         0
6        BAGHJAN         0
7  Duliajan Area         2
8      LANGKASHI         0
9         HAPJAN         2
```

Comment: How can I get the whole value instead of float.

Comment: @venkateswaran, what do you mean whole value?

Comment: Instead of 2.0, 0.0. I need 0,2 like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas `merge` function
for example:

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns={"Location": "index"})
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="index")
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat your dataframe then drop duplicates:

```
mapping = {'index': 'Location', 'Count': 'Category'}
out = (pd.concat([df2, df1.rename(columns=mapping)])
         .drop_duplicates('Location', keep='last')
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print(out)

# Output
        Location  Category
0        NAGAJAN         0
1        JORAJAN         0
2         HEBEDA         0
3          MAKUM         0
4       BAREKURI         0
5        BAGHJAN         0
6      LANGKASHI         0
7  Duliajan Area         2
8         HAPJAN         2
9     KATHALGURI         2
```